# How can I make an SQL query to summarize data

Tags: mysql, html-table

I have to create this type of summary report:

```
---------------------------------------------------
Medicine Name | Novartis | Glaxo | Roche | Nestle
---------------------------------------------------
Medicine-A    | 20.3 | 20 | 25 | 30 |
--------------------------------------
Medicine-B    | 19 | 15 | 18 | 20 |
-------------------------------------
Medicine-C    | 100 | 95 | 95 | 98 |
-------------------------------------
```

It is table of bidding summary, i.e Rate of Medicines of Novartis, Glaxo, Roche & Nestle. I have to create a html table using the data.

Now I have two mysql tables.

```
Table:1 (Name of Medicine):
------------------------------
Medicine Name | Type | Bidding Year | 
------------------------------
Medicine-A    | Tablet | 2014 | 
------------------------------
Medicine-B    | Capsule | 2014 |
-----------------------------
Medicine-C    | Oinment | 2014 |
-----------------------------

Table: 2 (Rate of Medicine):
------------------------------
Medicine Name | Company | Rate | 
------------------------------
Medicine-A    | Novartis | 20.3 | 
------------------------------
Medicine-A    | Glaxo | 20 |
-----------------------------
Medicine-A    | Roche| 25 |
-----------------------------
Medicine-A    | Nestle | 30 |
-----------------------------
Medicine-B    | Roche| 19 |
-----------------------------
Medicine-B    | Novartis | 15 | 
------------------------------
Medicine-B    | Glaxo | 18 |
-----------------------------
Medicine-B    | Roche| 20 |
-----------------------------
Medicine-A    | Nestle | 20 |
-----------------------------
Medicine-C    | Novartis| 100 |
------------------------------
Medicine-A    | Glaxo | 95 |
-----------------------------
Medicine-A    | Roche| 95 |
-----------------------------
Medicine-A    | Nestle| 98 |
-----------------------------
```

How can I make an SQL query and how to fetch the data so that an html table (1st table) can be made easily?

Comment: Do you need something like this? `SELECT name, company, SUM(rate) AS sum FROM table GROUP BY name, company`

Comment: Are you looking for the max(Rate) of every Company for each of Medicins?

Comment: Nope, Please look at first table. I want to summarize the data. There in column heading company names will be available whereas in rows, name of the medicine will be available and under each company's column, price of that respective medicine rate will be available (no sum, but all the price).

Comment: I see, I think you should search about "pivot table". And if the Companies are more than the 4 you mentioned or in the future new Company names will be added etc you should look for "dynamic pivot"